# Merge rows into one based on full stop

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc

I have a table in the following format.

---

all that is

---

well known for

---

let be apples.

---

abs kdjhkj kfhksh sh

---

kjsfhkshgkh dh.

---

I want the rows to merge based on the fullstop, whenever a full stop comes, a new row should be created untill next full stop occurs.
example

---

all that is well known for let be apples.

---

abs kdjhkj kfhksh sh kjsfhkshgkh dh.

---

I see we can merge by n number of rows into one using inbuild tools. But I have a huge list, I cannot go around and do that for each set. 
Any solution, in code or through excel or libreoffice calc will be helpful.
though I can try macro but not preferring that. Anyways if that is the only way to achieve it then why not.

Comment: Will it be in same column, for example , only A column or B Column

Comment: Looks like its possible only with vba

Comment: @PASUMPONVN yes all the information is in one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way to archive this with excel function. i try to create a code fulfill your needs:

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim str As String
    Dim i As Long, LastRowA As Long, LastRowC As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRowA

            If InStr(1, .Range("A" & i).Value, ".") > 0 Then

                If str = "" Then
                    str = .Range("A" & i).Value
                Else
                    str = str & " " & .Range("A" & i).Value
                End If

                LastRowC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

                If LastRowC = 1 And .Range("C1").Value = "" Then
                    .Range("C" & LastRowC).Value = str
                Else
                    .Range("C" & LastRowC + 1).Value = str
                End If

                str = ""

            Else

                If str = "" Then
                    str = .Range("A" & i).Value
                Else
                    str = str & " " & .Range("A" & i).Value
                End If

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just import it in a google drive you can do it with:

=SPLIT(CONCATENATE(A1:A5);".")

You can do it in excel by using concatenate in the same way and then also separating by "." but I do not think you can't split in that way to my knowledge. In any case, in VBA is not a difficult code. But I guess you just want to solve this and you are doing it in excel beceause you don't know how to do it in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is effective compare to first answer.

```
    Sub Program1()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Str1 As String
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To Lastrow
        If InStr(1, ws.Cells(i, 1).Value, ".") > 0 Then
            ws.Cells(j, 3).Value = Str1 & ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
            j = j + 1
            Str1 = ""
        Else
            Str1 = Str1 & ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next
   End Sub
```